# How to Remove author credits on posts on my wordpress site?

Tags: php, html, wordpress

How do I remove the date added/admin/no comments section of each one of my posts in my wordpress blog here http://www.kvylfm.com

Comment: Please say how far you have got - this will narrow down what we need to work out. Most importantly - are you supposed to be able to remove them? If so, are you able to upload stylesheets to the page? If so then it should be easy to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, but check in loop.php in your theme... There is a function called something like posted_on();... remove that and is done... there is a function for each  thing, just find it, and remove it :)

Answer (score 0):

The code that needs to be removed/commented out should be in your index.php/home.php, page.php and post.php but this can vary from theme to theme. Please post the loop from your page.php file and I can then update my answer with more specific directions.

**UPDATE**

This is pretty hard to figure out without having the theme's source code, but as an alternative, you can hide those elements. Open your `style.css` file and paste these two lines at the end of the file:

```
.post-date, .post-info { display: none; }
.post-content { clear: both; }
```

This should do the trick.

Comment: here is my page.php <?php
 /* Mystique/digitalnature */
 get_header();
?>

  <!-- main content: primary + sidebar(s) -->
  <div id="main">
   <div id="main-inside" class="clear-block">
    <!-- primary content -->
    <div id="primary-content">
     <div class="blocks">
       <?php do_action('mystique_before_primary'); ?>
       <?php

        if (have_posts()):
         while (have_posts()):
          the_post();
          mystique_page();
         endwhile;
        endif;

        comments_template();
       ?>
       <?php do_action('mystique_after_primary'); ?>
     </div>
    </div>

Comment: I wouldn't advise posting any passwords or sensitive info as this is all public and everyone can see it. Look in your web root, navigate to `wp-content > themes > name_of_your_theme` open page.php and post its contents by editing your original question.

Comment: Thank you so much! Why was it so hard for me to get an answer on that? Did I not present it artfully? I asked on stackoverflow twice and on ardvark 3 times.

Comment: By the way spent 4 weeks in Iasi and loved every minute of it! Went when I was 13 and went to school while I was there. Truly a once in a life time experience for boy from the deserts of Arizona. In fact I was at the opening of the first McDonald's in Bucharest.

Comment: You're welcome :) The problem was that you wanted to **remove** those bits, which is very hard without having a look at the PHP source. What I gave you is merely a workaround -- those elements are still there, just hidden. Either way, if this was helpful, please feel free to accept the answer as you'll have more chances of getting an answer in the future if your accept ratio is high.

Answer (score 0):

In your single.php and index.php files, remove this line:

```
<div class="post-info">Posted by <?php the_author() ?> on <?php the_time('F jS, Y') ?> | <?php comments_popup_link('0 comments', '1 comment', '% comments'); ?></div><div style="clear: both;"></div>
```

Hope that helps!